# React native Expo app -- how to serve on IP, not localhost?

Tags: react-native, expo

This is a new problem for me after rebuilding my development machine.  When I launch my CRNA app, it's served at exp://localhost:19000
Obviously, neither my phone nor my emulator can find the app at that address, so how do I make it serve the app on my IP?

I've tried setting the REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME env variable to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
npm i -g exp
exp start --dev --lan
```

Answer (score 1):

you can read the full [DOC](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/exp-cli.html) from expo and use `exp start --dev --lan` .

but you can install Expo XDE (windows/macOs) and select lan in host setting!